# Publishing to a Gazebo Topic by Terminal

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can I pub a test message to a specific Gazebo topic using a terminal line command?

I am looking for something like the command **rostopic pub** for ROS, but for Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16986/publishing-to-a-gazebo-topic-by-terminal/) by [ItzMeJP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2944/itzmejp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

there is a command  line tool but it's not exactly the same as rostopic pub. You can send commands like modifying model/camera/joint properties, etc but you can't publish commands to arbitrary gazebo topics.

type `gz help` for more info

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ItzMeJP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2944/itzmejp/) on 2017-08-15**:
I already did it and no options help me.

Is there any code example  (in C++) of a simple publish (to a exist random topic) for gazebo?

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-08-16**:
there is a publisher example in the repo:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/examples/stand_alone/publisher/

**Comment by [ItzMeJP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2944/itzmejp/) on 2017-08-16**:
This link is broken =/

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2017-08-16**:
one more time: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2c58f1f337662a7ca4b85b5230b8c26a285f6682/examples/stand_alone/publisher?at=default

**Comment by [ItzMeJP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2944/itzmejp/) on 2017-08-16**:
Now it works, thank you. It is what I am looking for.

**Comment by [corot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1105/corot/) on 2021-04-17**:
ups...  link broken again (after almost 4 yr).  Is the example still available?

**Comment by [JakobThumm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46581/jakobthumm/) on 2021-06-22**:
https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/examples/stand_alone/publisher/publisher.cc

**Comment by [JakobThumm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46581/jakobthumm/) on 2021-06-22**:
Calling `gazebo::setupClient();` is absolutely necessary, even if gazebo is already running.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

gz command can help here. I use it to send joint commands to the pioneer2dx, for example:

```
gz joint -m pioneer2dx -j left_wheel_hinge --vel-t 1.0 --vel-p 1.0
```

This will send a joint command to the joint left_wheel_hinge of the model named pioneer2dx. The message is sent as a one-shot so may not do what you want, but it can be useful for testing.

---

Originally posted by [craig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3779/craig/) with karma: 23 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2